# bs4 - How to find only paragraphs with quotes in them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to figure out how to find all paragraphs in a website (https://www.shortlist.com/news/most-ridiculous-trump-quotes-ever) and only store the paragraphs with quotes in them. I am using bs4 to parse the data and requests to get the website content. I can't figure out how to only store the paragraphs that have quotes in them. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. In the end I basically want to store all of the quotes in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to just select the first `p` paragraph after the `h3` header that starts with `"On"` (this way you skip random `h3`'s).

```py
{p.text: p.find_next("p").text for p in soup.select("div > h3") if p.text.startswith("On")}
```

sample output:

```
{'On domestic policy': '"I think if this country gets any kinder or gentler, it\'s literally going to cease to exist."\r\n',
 'On immigration': '“Why are we having all these people from shithole countries coming here?”\r\n',
 'On Syrian refugees': '"What I won\'t do is take in two hundred thousand Syrians who could be ISIS... I have been watching this migration. And I see the people. I mean, they\'re men. They\'re mostly men, and they\'re strong men. These are physically young, strong men. They look like prime-time soldiers. Now it\'s probably not true, but where are the women?... So, you ask two things. Number one, why aren\'t they fighting for their country? And number two, I don\'t want these people coming over here."\r\n',
 'On border control': '"I will build a great, great wall on our southern border, and I will have Mexico pay for that wall. Mark my words."\r\n',
```